# Height of white space above header in chrome while converting to pdf

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, puppeteer, printing-web-page

What is the size of the white space visible above the header in the Chromium/Chrome when converting to pdf? Is it hardcoded somewhere in the source?

[Space above header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o1X36.jpg)

Comment: Are you talking about the [`page.pdf`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions) function of puppeteer or of the print dialog of the Chrome browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The header is part of the margin of the page which can be specified when calling [`page.pdf`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagepdfoptions). By default, this value is set to no margin.

As an example: To make sure, there are `20mm` of space at the top for your header, you can use the following code:

```js
await page.pdf({
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    headerTemplate: '<div style="font-size:10mm;">Some header text</div>',
    margin: {
        top: '20mm',
        bottom: '0',
        right: '0',
        left: '0'
    },
    path: 'file.pdf',
});
```

---

In case you are interested in the default margins of Chrome to use them in puppeteer, you can find them in the print dialog, when you switch from "Default" to "Custom" (`0.4 inch`):

[image: Chrome print dialog]

Comment: Thanks for your analysis. Yes, I am looking to find the top margin dynamically based on header content height. So to find the top margin, I need to add the height white space above the header + content height + height of white space again.

I tried looking into the source for finding the value and couldn't find it.

Comment: @SanthoshManikandan The margin contains your header. That means, you should set `margin` to a value that is greater than the height of your header content.

Comment: Yeah that's correct. But the problem I face is that fonts are rendered in the header/footer are of bigger size than the configured one.

Comment: @SanthoshManikandan So the fonts you specify are not applied? I'm not sure if I understand you correct. This sounds like a very different question than your original one. Maybe you want to create another question? :)

Comment: Thanks, Thomas. Will try to fix it before creating a new question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that white space is added due to the style tag present in the [template](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/printing/resources/print_header_footer_template_page.html?l=19) used for converting to pdf.